# looping ggscatter function for unique combinations of x,y variables from dataframe columns

Tags: r, loops, statistics, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I need to draw scatterplots for evaluation of linear regression. I want to use "ggscatter" function but I need to write loops.

I have checked many examples on this platform and other sites, but I couldn't find a suitable solution.

Data need to be introduced as 45 unique combinations of x,y variables corresponding to separate columns. So there will be 45 plots and these plots can be drawn as subplots in a multiplot figure with 4 columns and 4 rows. So, output will be 3 figure files.

For example, unique x,y combinations are A,B; A,C; A,D; ... B,C; B,D; B,E; ... H,I; H,J; and I,J.

x and y change as pairs instead of one of them being constant.

Dimensions of the dataframe is ncol=10, nrow=28

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0.99    0.13    0.88    0.07    7.83    3.63    6.78    14.5    76.7    880.3
0.29    0.84    0.75    0.93    2.69    7.71    8.23    84.7    12.9    476.8
0.54    0.22    0.99    0.60    8.57    8.53    4.56    79.1    21.3    686.9
0.84    0.89    0.82    0.50    0.48    8.40    2.96    24.5    35.5    300.1
0.58    0.98    0.86    0.41    3.05    6.48    2.36    75.5    43.5    993.4
0.21    0.78    0.64    0.90    3.32    3.03    0.02    89.2    18.1    358.0
0.07    0.46    0.66    0.42    2.97    9.35    0.42    68.2    59.2    576.5
0.19    0.01    0.89    0.69    6.59    6.93    4.23    46.6    74.1    299.7
0.33    0.05    0.60    0.58    9.86    1.37    5.20    79.2    28.9    494.1
0.25    0.50    0.01    0.29    7.64    6.23    4.80    48.4    96.5    762.2
0.30    0.96    0.71    0.85    6.89    5.08    0.48    50.3    80.8    396.7
0.03    0.18    0.25    0.56    0.57    3.83    7.91    58.5    43.6    201.7
0.59    0.62    0.74    0.62    0.59    0.00    2.62    63.3    51.6    416.0
0.53    0.18    0.21    0.96    9.68    1.80    1.71    69.5    28.4    584.1
0.25    0.05    0.46    0.92    9.16    2.64    8.15    24.5    80.7    699.0
0.33    0.88    0.99    0.70    1.60    5.38    0.26    64.4    60.0    265.3
0.06    0.57    0.75    0.69    5.55    0.02    0.77    47.5    82.4    729.1
0.90    0.55    0.26    0.26    1.38    6.24    0.31    28.4    61.5    181.5
0.77    0.74    0.42    0.94    3.35    7.75    3.46    22.2    78.5    347.8
0.61    0.16    0.98    0.51    8.81    8.27    3.86    42.4    67.8    303.1
0.26    0.58    0.71    0.24    1.97    9.14    5.67    65.6    63.9    967.4
0.16    0.35    0.26    0.23    4.25    3.98    9.07    99.2    83.6    817.9
0.71    0.87    0.31    0.94    0.55    5.72    0.15    86.3    41.8    579.1
0.23    0.45    0.19    0.45    0.10    0.52    5.53    46.8    47.7    788.5
0.57    0.82    0.68    0.55    2.23    6.83    4.93    67.2    94.4    482.7
0.93    0.26    0.89    0.48    6.85    3.95    6.82    76.2    88.9    551.9
0.70    0.72    0.02    0.99    1.07    0.62    8.03    19.4    88.9    355.9
0.06    0.24    0.46    0.74    5.18    1.15    8.69    18.4    100.0   676.7
```

R script is as follows:

```
setwd("working_directory")
data <- read.table("data.txt", header=TRUE)
attach(data)

str(data)

### It was possible to draw histograms as below
### Multiple histogram plot (uses single x variable with plot function) 

library(rcompanion)

histplot <- function (df) {
    plots <- vector('list', ncol(df))

    for (i in seq_along(df)) {
        plots[[i]] <- local({
            i <- i
            p1 <- plotNormalHistogram(df[[i]], 
                prob=FALSE,
                main=paste("Histogram of",colnames(df[i]),"\n with Std.Norm. Curve"))
        })
    }
}

dev.new()
par(mfrow=c(3,4))
histplot(data)

### Multiple scatterplot (uses two variable (x,y) with plot function)

### There are 45 unique combinations for 10 different data columns and I need to write a loop for this plot, but I couldn't write it 

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

### multiplot function for defining subplot layouts with ggplot functions 

multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
  require(grid)

  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

  numPlots = length(plots)

  if (is.null(layout)) {
    layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                    ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
  }

 if (numPlots==1) {
    print(plots[[1]])

  } else {
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
      matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))

      print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                      layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
  }
}

### scatterplot function (I need a loop after here but I couldn't write it)

dev.new()

p1 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="B", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="B")
p2 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="C", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="C")
p3 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="D", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="D")
p4 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="E", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="E")
p5 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="F", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="F")
p6 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="G", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="G")
p7 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="H", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="H")
p8 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="I", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="I")
p9 <- ggscatter(data, x="A",y="J", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="A", ylab="J")
p10 <- ggscatter(data, x="B",y="C", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="B", ylab="C")
p11 <- ggscatter(data, x="B",y="D", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="B", ylab="D")
p12 <- ggscatter(data, x="B",y="E", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="B", ylab="E")
p13 <- ggscatter(data, x="B",y="F", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="B", ylab="F")
p14 <- ggscatter(data, x="B",y="G", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="B", ylab="G")
p15 <- ggscatter(data, x="B",y="H", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="B", ylab="H")
p16 <- ggscatter(data, x="B",y="I", add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab="B", ylab="I")

multiplot(plotlist = list(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16), cols = 4)

dev.new()

p17 <- ...
.
.
p32 <- ...

multiplot(...)

dev.new()

p33 <- ...
.
.
p45 <- ...

multiplot(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (I used `plot_grid` from `cowplot` instead of `multiplot` to keep the reproducible example shorter)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: magrittr
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> ********************************************************
#> Note: As of version 1.0.0, cowplot does not change the
#>   default ggplot2 theme anymore. To recover the previous
#>   behavior, execute:
#>   theme_set(theme_cowplot())
#> ********************************************************
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggpubr':
#> 
#>     get_legend

data <- structure(list(A = c(0.99, 0.29, 0.54, 0.84, 0.58, 0.21, 0.07, 0.19, 0.33, 0.25, 0.3, 0.03, 0.59, 0.53, 0.25, 0.33, 0.06, 0.9, 0.77, 0.61, 0.26, 0.16, 0.71, 0.23, 0.57, 0.93, 0.7, 0.06), B = c(0.13, 0.84, 0.22, 0.89, 0.98, 0.78, 0.46, 0.01, 0.05, 0.5, 0.96, 0.18, 0.62, 0.18, 0.05, 0.88, 0.57, 0.55, 0.74, 0.16, 0.58, 0.35, 0.87, 0.45, 0.82, 0.26, 0.72, 0.24), C = c(0.88, 0.75, 0.99, 0.82, 0.86, 0.64, 0.66, 0.89, 0.6, 0.01, 0.71, 0.25, 0.74, 0.21, 0.46, 0.99, 0.75, 0.26, 0.42, 0.98, 0.71, 0.26, 0.31, 0.19, 0.68, 0.89, 0.02, 0.46), D = c(0.07, 0.93, 0.6, 0.5, 0.41, 0.9, 0.42, 0.69, 0.58, 0.29, 0.85, 0.56, 0.62, 0.96, 0.92, 0.7, 0.69, 0.26, 0.94,0.51, 0.24, 0.23, 0.94, 0.45, 0.55, 0.48, 0.99, 0.74), E = c(7.83, 2.69, 8.57, 0.48, 3.05, 3.32, 2.97, 6.59, 9.86, 7.64, 6.89, 0.57, 0.59, 9.68, 9.16, 1.6, 5.55, 1.38, 3.35, 8.81, 1.97, 4.25, 0.55, 0.1, 2.23, 6.85, 1.07, 5.18), F = c(3.63, 7.71, 8.53, 8.4, 6.48, 3.03, 9.35, 6.93, 1.37, 6.23, 5.08, 3.83, 0, 1.8, 2.64, 5.38, 0.02, 6.24, 7.75, 8.27, 9.14, 3.98, 5.72, 0.52, 6.83, 3.95, 0.62, 1.15), G = c(6.78, 8.23, 4.56, 2.96, 2.36, 0.02, 0.42, 4.23, 5.2, 4.8, 0.48, 7.91, 2.62, 1.71, 8.15, 0.26, 0.77, 0.31, 3.46, 3.86, 5.67, 9.07, 0.15, 5.53, 4.93, 6.82, 8.03, 8.69), H = c(14.5, 84.7, 79.1, 24.5, 75.5, 89.2, 68.2, 46.6, 79.2, 48.4, 50.3, 58.5, 63.3, 69.5, 24.5, 64.4, 47.5, 28.4, 22.2, 42.4, 65.6, 99.2, 86.3, 46.8, 67.2, 76.2, 19.4, 18.4), I = c(76.7, 12.9, 21.3, 35.5, 43.5, 18.1, 59.2, 74.1, 28.9, 96.5, 80.8, 43.6, 51.6, 28.4, 80.7, 60, 82.4, 61.5, 78.5, 67.8, 63.9, 83.6, 41.8, 47.7, 94.4, 88.9, 88.9, 100), J = c(880.3, 476.8, 686.9, 300.1, 993.4, 358, 576.5, 299.7, 494.1, 762.2, 396.7, 201.7, 416, 584.1, 699, 265.3, 729.1, 181.5, 347.8, 303.1, 967.4, 817.9, 579.1, 788.5, 482.7, 551.9, 355.9, 676.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))
plotComb <- combn(colnames(data), 2, simplify = FALSE)
scatterfn <- function(l, data=data){
  ggscatter(data, x=l[1], y=l[2], add="reg.line", conf.int=TRUE, cor.coef=TRUE, cor.method="pearson", xlab=l[1], ylab=l[2])
}
plots <- lapply(plotComb, scatterfn, data=data)
plots <- split(plots, ceiling(seq_along(plots)/16))
pdf(file="Rplot1.pdf", width=12, height=12)
lapply(plots, function(x) plot_grid(plotlist=x, cols=4))
dev.off()
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>